# How to solve problem in APK Tools

Tags: android

I'm trying to decompile an apk with the apk tools and I'm not getting it.

When I run `apktool -d myapp.apk` it displays this error to me:

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Invalid chunk type: expected=0x00000200, got=0x00000203
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.checkChunkType(ARSCDecoder.java:542)
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTablePackage(ARSCDecoder.java:88)
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTableHeader(ARSCDecoder.java:82)
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:48)
at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:786)
at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:67)
at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:59)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:66)
at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.setTargetSdkVersion(ApkDecoder.java:236)
at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:118)
at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:170)
at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Can anyone help me with that?

I'm doing this to insert a payload manually in the apk and I need to do this

Comment: Without knowing the file, we're only guessing as to why you are getting an error.

Comment: So, the problem is in the apk, when I researched this error, I already had a report of this error on Github on the creator page of the tool, what he said is that this error is related to the `ARSC` library, I tested it with another apk and  it worked well, but I don't know why it gave this error, I didn't understand it well, I don't want to have problems with the apk I'm going to test.  I wanted a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can now build it yourself from the official [APKtool github site](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool), following [the easy-to-follow official instructions](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/build/). In only a few minutes.

I tried with an apk that had been giving this error.

When I used apktool_2.5.0.jar (the most recent release, Dec 2020), from [Apktool release site](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/), the error was seen.

After building apktool from the source, and trying on the same apk, it worked perfectly without the error.